# Should I switch my monitor to using DisplayPort rather than DVI-D?

Tags: dvi, displayport

Is there any advantage to switiching the cable that I use for my monitor from a DVI-D cable to a DisplayPort cable? Or is there no noticable difference between the two? My monitor is working fine at the moment but I have a spare DisplayPort cable and was wondering if I should switch or not?

Any help is appreciated :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably no advantage. Both are digital formats and there should be no image quality difference between those two.

The only reason two switch are:

- If you have a monitor with speakers and you are now using both a DVI cable and an audio cable. (thus using less cables)
- If you have multiple display port monitors and you want to chain them, so you use less cables. (Unlikely with the current hardware, but slowly becoming more common).
- If you want to connect two monitors, and the other monitor has no display port.
- If you have a single link DVI cable and a monitor which can handle higher resolutions that the single link cable supports. (Dual link DVI cables would also solve this).

From the OP I think only the first option could be relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I have the Dell U2711 and it is working fine at the maximum resolution so I guess I'll stick to what I have.